# Not able to implement Jeremy Feinstein sliding menu in a class which extends Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented tabview using this code displayed in below URL:

http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/

I also have implemented sliding menu library (from Jeremy Feinstein..link is below).

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

The problem is Tab class is extending fragment and when I add sliding menu code in that class it gives error on :

```
slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
```

and also on these methods :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (slidingMenu.isMenuShowing()) {
            slidingMenu.toggle();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            this.slidingMenu.toggle();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Please help me out with this problem
Thanks..

Comment: The SlidingMenu is supposed to be attached to activities, not fragments..

Comment: Tabhost is deprecated by android...So how do I Use Tab layout that also work with sliding menu activity ?

Comment: TabWidget uses Tabhost..which extends TabActivity...Which is depreceted by android....So is it advisable to use TabActivity ??

Comment: You don't need a TabActivity. Check out the Action Bar Sherlock Tab navigation demo: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java